# Transfer formula value to variable

Tags: excel, vba

Code: VBA

```
Sheets("Facebook").Activate

catcount(1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(cndtnltrnsfr.Col_Letter(posval(1)) & "2:" & cndtnltrnsfr.Col_Letter(posval(1)) & emptyRow & "," & chr(34) & cat(1) & chr(34))

MsgBox catcount(1)
```

`catcount(1)` : an array in which the number of times a category is occurring is stored

`posval(1)` : an array which stores the position of a specific value

`cat(1)` : category

It is giving an error

> Argument not optional!

and highlighting `.Countif`.

Answer (score 1):

The [WorksheetFunction.CountIf](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839272.aspx) method takes 2 arguments and you only have one  in this long concatenation :

```
cndtnltrnsfr.Col_Letter(posval(1)) & "2:" & cndtnltrnsfr.Col_Letter(posval(1)) & emptyRow & "," & chr(34) & cat(1) & chr(34)
```

Maybe you should change this :

```
& "," &
```

to this :

```
,
```

I can't answer more with what you have asked and shown.